# On mobile devices there is a steady 33% of undelivered push notifications ratio, and I have no idea why

Tags: android, web-push

I have a website, where I register a service-worker for the users. I save the push notification subscription info on the backend, and send push notifications at specific times of the day. Since my users live mostly in a different time-zone, I utilize a queue which can send the push at the right time.

I save the stats in the service worker through http requests, make a hop to track the url also if the user clicks the push notification. I also track, how many push notifications I try to send according to my queue consumer service.

For some reason there is a steady 33% of undelivered messages according to the service-worker statistics. For example:
lets say I send about 20.000 push notifications a day, and the 'displayed' event fires only about 12.000-14.000 times according to the service-worker.

Anyone has any idea why this could happen?

- On chrome desktop every single one of tens of thousands of push notifications arrive.
- On mobile devices they are not.
  This implies that the fault either lies in the google-service, or the service-workers compatibility with some mobile devices

```
import { serviceWorkerRoutes } from 'src/route-config';

const requestParams = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  method: 'POST'
};

self.addEventListener('install', () => {
  // the service worker must be activated as soon as it's finished installing
  self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
  if (event.data) {
    const data = event.data.json();
    const {
      badge,
      body,
      icon,
      image,
      actions,
      title,
      url,
      sent_at: sentAt,
    } = data;

    const options = {
      badge,
      body,
      actions,
      data: {
        actions,
        sentAt,
        url,
      },
      icon,
      image,
      requireInteraction: true
    };

    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));

    return fetch(serviceWorkerRoutes.measurements, {
      ...requestParams,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        indicator: 'PUSH_NOTIFICATION_DISPLAYED',
        sentAt,
      })
    });
  }

  return fetch(serviceWorkerRoutes.measurements, {
    ...requestParams,
    body: JSON.stringify({ indicator: 'PUSH_NOTIFICATION_DATA_MISSING' })
  });
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
  const { notification } = event;
  const hasActions = event.action && notification.data && notification.data.actions;
  let { url } = notification.data;

  notification.close();

  if (hasActions) {
    const action = notification.data.actions.find((item) => item.action === event.action);
    url = action ? action.url : url;
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  const promiseChain = clients.openWindow(url);
  event.waitUntil(promiseChain);

  return fetch(serviceWorkerRoutes.measurements, {
    ...requestParams,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      indicator: 'PUSH_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED',
      action: event.action,
      sentAt: notification.data && notification.data.sentAt
    })
  });
});

self.addEventListener('pushsubscriptionchange',
  () => fetch(serviceWorkerRoutes.measurements, {
    ...requestParams,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      indicator: 'PUSH_NOTIFICATION_SUBSCRIPTION_CHANGED',
      sentAt: new Date().toISOString()
    })
  }));

self.addEventListener('notificationclose',
  (event) => fetch(serviceWorkerRoutes.measurements, {
    ...requestParams,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      indicator: 'PUSH_NOTIFICATION_CLOSED',
      sentAt: event.notification.data && event.notification.data.sentAt
    })
  }));
```